# Video height difference in chrome and mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

I am getting different height while using a video:

```
#myVideo{
position: absolute;
z-index: 4;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
top:0;
right:0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-bottom: -100px;
background-color: black; 
background-image: /* our video */;
background-position: center center;
background-size: contain;
object-fit: cover;
}

<video autoplay loop muted id="myVideo">
<source src="imgs/flowers.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="imgs/flowers.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

How can I solve this different heights in chrome and mozilla.

Comment: Could you give us a link so we can try it? I think your problem is being caused by the parent container of #myVideo. However the property you are using (object-fit, background-image etc.) shouldn't be used for a video tag.

Comment: http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/examples/videoBackground.html

Comment: you're relying on  the browsers native video player controls which of course will vary between browsers. Consider using an overlay such as [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) or roll your own